# Sublime Text 3 syntax definition: how to capture a multiline C-style block comment?

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

So the target block is like this:

```
/* some comments
   more
   end  */
```

Anything between `/*` and `*/` is considered comment. My current rule just captures single line comments:

```
match: \/\*(\w|\s|\W|\n|\r\n)*\*\/
```

I know Sublime Text uses [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) but I'm not sure how to match multilines.

Comment: What's wrong with the syntax definitions that comes with ST3?

Comment: This is for a custom file type that doesn't have a ST syntax definition yet. For comments, it uses C-style block comment.

Comment: Then copy the one from the C syntax definition? That's what I did when adding syntax definitions for a new language.

Comment: Hm. Good point. It looks like `.sublime-package` is simply a zip file so I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with ST3 but with a `.sublime-syntax` file. The difference is that in my language the block comments are bounded by `!*` and `*!`. An inline comment starts with `!`.

Here is the solution I used:

```
contexts:
  # The prototype context is prepended to all contexts but those setting
  # meta_include_prototype: false.
  prototype:
    - include: comments
  comments:
    # Block comments begin with !* and ends with *!
    - match: '!\*'
      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.c
      push: 
        - meta_scope: comment.block.c
        - match: '\*!'
          pop: true
    # Inline comments begin with a '!' and finish at the end of the line.
    - match: '![^\*]'
      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.c
      push:
        # This is an anonymous context push for brevity.
        - meta_scope: comment.line.double-slash.c
        - match: $\n?
          pop: true
```

Answer (score 2):

OK. So [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg)'s comment was very helpful. Here's how I did it.

#### Approach

1- Install [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) package.

2- Copy the relevant package to a temporary directory and unzip it. For `C`, I did this:

```
cp /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/C++.sublime-package ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
unzip C++.sublime-package
```

Unzipping will create many `*.tmLanguage` files.

3- Open `C.tmLanguage` in Sublime.

4- From the Command Palette, choose `Build with: covert to ... YAML (Block Style)` which will create `C.YAML-tmLanguage`.

5- Then open up the `YAML` file and copy the regex that you need.

#### Answer

For C-style blocks, this rule worked:

```
- begin: /\*
  captures:
    '0':
      name: punctuation.definition.comment.mn
  end: \*/
  name: comment.block.c
```